# Can I call an overridden method from the super of the super?

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, dynamic-binding

Assume that I have these three classes:

```
class Foo {
    void fn() {
        System.out.println("fn in Foo");
    }
}

class Mid extends Foo {
    void fn() {
        System.out.println("fn in Mid");
    }
}

class Bar extends Mid {
    void fn() {
        System.out.println("fn in Bar");
    }

    void gn() {
        Foo f = (Foo) this;
        f.fn();
    }
}

public class Trial {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Bar b = new Bar();
        b.gn();
    }
}
```

Is it possible to call a `Foo`'s `fn()`? I know that my solution in `gn()` doesn't work because `this` is pointing to an object of type `Bar`.

Comment: Does this even compiles?

Comment: of-course !! what is the problem??

Comment: I''ve overlooked that methods are private

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible in Java. You can use `super` but it always uses the method in immediate superclass in type hierarchy.

Also note that this:

```
Foo f = (Foo) this;
f.fn();
```

is the very definition of <strike>polymoprhism</strike> how virtual call works: even though `f` is of type `Foo`, but at runtime `f.fn()` is dispatched to `Bar.fn()`. Compile-time type doesn't matter.